# Joomla 3.0 Extension manager warning

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I got the following error messages when I try to install new modules, or plugins in Joomla 3.0

```
Warning
Warning: Failed to move file!

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/u490546148/public_html/tmp/install_543bc382bf809

JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/u490546148/public_html/tmp/install_543bc382bf809

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/u490546148/public_html/tmp/install_543bc382bf809

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file
```

Note:- I tried to install Joomla 3.0 Pure III Template but after that I got error like this

Comment: Make sure your temporary directory has been defined correctly in the Joomla Global Configuration

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so] site! I suggest to ask the question at [joomla.stackexchnge.com](http://joomla.stackexchnge.com), it is more specialized on Joomla problems.

Comment: but i didn't change any thing in Global configuration

Comment: Each of the errors you're getting when show alone, have their separate meanings, but because they are all displayed together, it normally means that the tmp directory isn't defined correctly. You simply change the directly and ensure it's pointed to the correct folder

Comment: Ok i will check hope it will work